# ListView row id and position index confusion

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I'm just starting to dive into some basic Android development and have been experimenting with a `ListView` and integrating it with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. I look through a lot of online code samples, but I also have a book to use as a reference (Professional Android 2 Application Development).

In the book they work out an example To-Do list application that stores the list items in a SQLite database with an auto-incrementing, integer, primary key field.

A user can create new list items, but can also delete a selected item from the list. In the code, when the delete occurs, the primary key field is restricted (within the `WHERE` clause of the SQL statement) by the `position` attribute of the item as opposed to the item's `rowid`.

To me, this seems like an incorrect implementation. Looking at the SQLite documentation for `AUTOINCREMENT`, it says that this value will always increase and old values will never be re-used on the same table. So if you're deleting and adding things to the list, it would seem that the position and row id can get out of sync rather quickly.

Am I correct, then, to assume that the row id is the correct way to "index" into the database table and **not** the list position? I think the position would be safe to use if one is using the regular `ListAdapter`, but doesn't seem suitable when indexing into the database.

Comment: Aren't they just using the list position to retrieve the row id and then delete off the row id?

Comment: Nope. They pass the position into a function that just runs the following: `return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + _rowIndex, null) > 0;` where `_rowIndex` is the position of the item, not the row id. This is called from a context menu callback and they pass the `menuInfo.position` as the `_rowIndex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is definitely bad practice. I always use the row id to delete, and use the position id to retrieve the cursor's row id. I have the first edition of that book at home, I'm going to take a look at it myself later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the position to get a cursor to a particular list entry (and this cursor would be the 'row' in the 'table' corresponding to the row id):

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
int rowCol = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
```

Then you should see that `cursor.getLong(rowCol) == id`

Comment: Ok, this looks sensible. So internally, the list knows how the positions map to the rows, so `getItemAtPosition()` should return the correct item. Thanks! (still not how it's done in the book and also not the first error I've found).