# Confusion between ListView id position and row ID

Tags: android, sql, listview

**Update**

Of course, right after I post this I figure out a way. Happens almost every time.

So I put my CursorAdapter outside my refresh database function so I could access it outside my refresh function. Then I implemented a

```
mDbHelper.deleteTask(tasks.getItemId(pos));
```

So that it find's the correct id based upon the position. Just gave this a few tests and seems to be working flawlessly along with my swipe gesture! If this is something that's frowned upon, please share!

---

So I'm extremely confused after going through a tutorial working with SQLite and ListView's. I have the list populated and I understand the concept of adding to the database and refreshing the view, but I can't seem to understand how to properly delete.

I understand that you pass into the SQL database a rowId which I've assigned to everything I add, auto incrementally then delete based off of that auto incremental rowId but how do you grab that correct rowId?

I can achieve the same affect of grabbing the position from my ListView using:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
int pos = lv.pointToPosition((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY());
```

Then I can throw it into my delete function

```
mDbHelper.deleteTask(pos);
```

And this will work correctly, but eventually the positions of the list position ID's and the SQL rowID's won't sync up properly over one or two deletions. I very much feel like I'm going at this all wrong.

It's similar to this problem: [ListView row id and position index confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658115/listview-row-id-and-position-index-confusion)

The answer says that it's bad practice the way I've been going about doing what I'm trying to do. Everything I see for examples online use the onContextMenu option but I want to use it for a gesture or using a series of checkboxes.

Here's my DataBaseHelper file or adapter I'm pretty sure it's referred to as:

```
package com.warner.taskswipe;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class TaskDatabaseHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tasks";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "task";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "description";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    //Creating our table with the setup for id, task, description
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, "
                + KEY_BODY + " text not null);";

    private final Context mCtx;

    //Constructor for our DatabaseHelper class to set the context object
    public TaskDatabaseHelper (Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            //Not used

        }

    }

    //Open the database
    public TaskDatabaseHelper open() throws android.database.SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //Close the database
    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    //Create a task
    public long createTask(String title, String description) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, description);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //Delete a task
    public boolean deleteTask(long rowId){
        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllTasks() {
        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY}, 
                                    null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor fetchTask(long rowId) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId,
                                    null, null, null, null, null);
        if(mCursor != null)
            mCursor.moveToFirst();

        return mCursor;
    }

    public boolean updateTask(long rowId, String title, String description){
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_BODY, description);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

   }
```

Thanks!